# Принцип работы вкладки "похожие записи" на сайте

Tags: php, javascript, html, cms

Интересует вопрос, по какому принципу работает скрип, который выводит записи, которые имеют близкий смысл к текущей статье.

Вот, например, вошли вы на чей-то сайт, читаете интересующую вас статью, а после ее прочтения, внизу страницы надпись: "Похожие записи".

И ниже список похожих статей на ту, которую вы прочли...

Так вот, как мне такое сделать?

Comment: теги ... редактор пишет статью, добавляет к ней теги "дтп, аварии, новости города, ГИБДД, ..." потом когда выводишь статью, смотришь какие у статьи id тегов, по этим тегам ищешь последние новости по этим тегам и выводишь их

Comment: а еще теги могут автогенерироваться автотегогенератором на основе анализа содержимого статьи при сохранении сообщения.. а еще страницы могут сопоставляться по аналогии с "с этим товаром также покупают" (если читали эту статью и потом другую - плюс один к весу связи, потом выбираем топ-10 самых толстых связей)... или по принадлежности к категории (ну скажем, при многоуровневой иерархии, рандомно дергаются статьи из соседней категории с общим предком)... а еще могут просто наугад... ну вы поняли, да? :)

Comment: в теории да, но так как у человека впринципе возник такой вопрос, то думаю про автогенирацию на основе анализа речь не идет )

Comment: Благодарю попробую с тегами

Comment: @Вадим а если теги расставляете не вы, то имеет смысл сравнивать их нечетко, приводя к нижнему регистру, удаляя все символы кроме букв и применяя к ним алгоритм Левенштейна http://php.net/manual/ru/function.levenshtein.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно показываются записи из той же категории или содержащие аналогичные теги или явно заданные администратором (возможно, в качестве скрытой рекламы).
Сильно сомневаюсь, что там идет разбор текста искусственным интеллектом с целью найти похожее по смыслу.
А вот показывать то, что может заинтересовать читателя, судя по поведению на сайте, вполне реально.
Короче, все зависит от того, что именно нужно и какой движок будет использован.

Answer (score 1):

Идей может быть много. Конечно, самое частое - это подбор по категориям и ключевым словам (тегам), но вы можете сильно озадачиться и, например, сделать запрос в бд по каждому слову из названия записи.

Вот есть у вас запись: "Дети Зеленого Леса" (например).

У вас в бд отправляется запрос на слово "дети", на слово "зеленого", и на слово "леса". У вас на выходе будет один из двух результатов:

1. Это будет что-то определенно интересное и новое (возможно даже улучшить это и удалять из поисковых слов окончания в будущем). Это будет интересно, думаю, тут есть момент психологии.
2. Абсолютный хлам